# Ordenar um arquivo com nome do player e score em C

Tags: c, arquivo, classificação, game

Tenho um arquivo `txt` de um game que estou desenvolvendo, a cada jogada, é salvo o `username` que o usuário digitou, e o score que ele pontuou ao fim da partida. no meu menu, tenho a opção de ver as pontuações, porém quero colocar em ordem decrescente, para que as maiores pontuações fiquem no topo, como um ranking. Quebrei muito a cabeça tentando fazer isso na minha função de salvar o score, mas não consegui utilizar o fgets() no modo `"a"` do fopen(), apenas no modo `"r"` - leitura.

Daí, tentei fazer a ordenação na função de mostrar os scores, já que para mostrar, uso o tipo "r", mesmo assim, não estou conseguindo.

Segue o código da minha função que exibe o conteúdo do arquivo "scores.txt" na tela, além do repositório no GitHub:

```
void showScores(){

    char ch;
    char eachScoreLine[7];
    int keyReceiver;
    int num = 0 ;
    int auxArray, smaller, bigger;
    char numberReceiver[10];

    char scoresReceiver[10][8];

    char indexCompare[3];

    int moduleCounter = 0;

    system("cls");
    printf("\n\t=== Arroba Catcher ===\n");
    printf("\n\t=== Melhores Pontuações === || \tAperte ESC para fechar.\n");
    printf("\n\tPlayer\t\tScore\n\t=====================\n");

    FILE *scoresFile;
    scoresFile = fopen("scores.txt", "r");

    //while para printar cada score
    while(fgets(eachScoreLine, 8, scoresFile) != NULL){
        moduleCounter++;

        //printa cada linha do arquivo
        printf("%s", eachScoreLine);
    }

    
    fclose(scoresFile);
    do{
        keyReceiver = getch();
    }while(keyReceiver != 27);
    closeSystem();
}
```

[Link para o repositório](https://github.com/pedrohsouza20/ArrobaCatcher)

Answer (score 0):

```
experimente usar o modo  "a+"
scoresFile = fopen("scores.txt", "a+");
```